# need to get the query right to get unique data count based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help in one of the query mention below , I want to have a count on id (Distinct) where condition are,
1) if all three structure associated to that id having STATUS AS "SUCCESS" then its called as delivered.
2)if any structure is having only 1 or 2 structure associated and there status is is success but one of the structure is missing then its pending.
3) if all three structure is present but any one of the structure status is failed then its been counted under pending.

this is the query i was written to get the below table,

```
   select m.id, p.group, p.structure, p.STATUS 
    from table_M m
    join table_O o on o.id = m.id
    join table_P p on ofenIdent.ref_id = p.ref_id
    where m.group = 'grp01'
      and p.status_flag = 'process' 
      and p.structure IN ('X','Y','Z')
    limit 50;


| id | group | structure    | STATUS  |
|------------|-----|-------------------|---------|
|        7 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        7 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        7 | grp01 |Y           | SUCCESS |
|        7 | grp01 |Y           | SUCCESS |
|        7 | grp01 | Z          | SUCCESS |
|        7 | grp01 | Z          | SUCCESS |
|        9 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        9 | grp01 |Y           | SUCCESS |
|        9 | grp01 | Z          | FAILURE |
|        0 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        0 | grp01 |Y           | SUCCESS |
|        0 | grp01 | Z          | FAILURE |
|        2 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        2 | grp01 |Y           | SUCCESS |
|        2 | grp01 | Z          | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        3 | grp01 | X          | SUCCESS |
|        3 | grp01 |Y           | SUCCESS |
|        3 | grp01 | Z          | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 |Y           | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 |Y           | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 |Y           | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 |Y           | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 |Y           | FAILURE |
|        4 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        4| grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z       | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z       | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z       | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z       | SUCCESS |
|        4 | grp01 | Z       | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | X        | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | X        | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | X        | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | X         | SUCCESS |
|        6 | grp01 | X         | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 |Y          | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 |Y          | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 |Y          | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 |Y          | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
|        5 | grp01 | Z         | SUCCESS |
```

This is with MYSQL db.

expected result should be like ,

```
Structure status |Total Count
-----------------|-----------
Delivered        | 2

Structure status |Total Count
-----------------|-----------
Pending          | 6
```

few more details as requested , i cant mention too much data , but here is what i can provide .

Table table_M :

```
M_id| id| group 
----|---|--------
1   |7  |grp01 
2   |9  |grp01
3   |0  |grp01
4   |2  |grp01
5   |4  |grp01
6   |5  |grp01
7   |6  |grp01
8   |3  |grp01
```

Table table_O:

```
O_id| id| ref_id 
----|---|-------
1   |0  |xxx01 
2   |1  |xxx02
3   |2  |xxx03
4   |3  |xxx04
5   |4  |xxx05
6   |5  |xxx06
7   |6  |xxx07
8   |7  |xxx08
```

Table table_P:

```
|P_id   | ref_id | structure| STATUS|group|status_code|
|--------|--------|----------|-------|-----|------------|
    1   |xxx01   |  X       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    2   |xxx01   |  Y       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    3   |xxx01   |  Z       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    4   |xxx02   |  X       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    5   |xxx03   |  X       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    6   |xxx03   |  Y       |FAILURE|grp01| 2|
    7   |xxx03   |  Z       |FAILURE|grp01| 2|
    8   |xxx04   |  X       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    8   |xxx04   |  Y       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    8   |xxx04   |  Z       |SUCCESS|grp01| 2|
    8   |xxx06   |  X       |FAILURE|grp02| 2|
    8   |xxx06   |  Y       |FAILURE|grp02| 2|
    8   |xxx06   |  Z       |FAILURE|grp02| 2|
```

Comment: Too much data. Show us some sample data **and** the expected result.

Comment: yes i added little more data so that it will be easier for me to explain things. uff its 2 hrs i am trying this . hope i have more knowledge on DB

Comment: It's not at all clear which tables contain which data or why you select p.group but you test for m.group or if ofenIdent is in fact table_o or what you mean by structure (is this actually table). It would help if you could show sample data from the 3 tables.

Comment: Sure , will update my question.

Comment: Is structure status "Pending" both for case 2) and 3)? Also, what is structure status supposed to be if a structure is missing and there is a failure as well?

Comment: 2)if any structure is having only X or (X and Y only ) with status as success/failure then also its named as pending.
3) if all three structure is present but any one of the structure status is failed then also its counted under pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT structure_status, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM (SELECT id,
        CASE
          -- Case 1
          WHEN success_count = 3 THEN 'Success'
          -- Case 2
          WHEN success_count > 0 AND failure_count = 0 THEN 'Pending'
          -- Case 3 - also called 'Pending'?
          WHEN total_count = 3 AND failure_count > 0 THEN 'Pending'
          -- Case 4 - what to do here?
          ELSE 'XXX'
        END structure_status
      FROM (SELECT m.id,
              count(*) total_count,
              count(CASE status WHEN 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 END) success_count,
              count(CASE status WHEN 'FAILURE' THEN 1 END) failure_count
            FROM table_M m
            JOIN table_O o ON o.id = m.id
            JOIN table_P p ON ofenIdent.ref_id = p.ref_id
            WHERE m.group = 'grp01'
              AND p.status_flag = 'process' 
              AND p.structure IN ('X','Y','Z')
            GROUP BY m.id) status_count
     ) structure_status_mapping
GROUP BY structure_status
```

Comment: I tried with your query but seems like could not find few parameters. can you check it once

Comment: Thanks a lot mark, made some changes as per my requirement and now its fully working ..

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  It is not intended to be a complete answer but it's too long for a comment.

```
select somefields to be discussed later
, count(distinct id) "Total Records"

from yourTable left join (
select id xid
, status xStatus
from yourTable
where structure = 'X' ) x on xid = yourTableId
)
-- repeat for Y and Z
group by somefields to be discussed later
```

The fields you actually want will be case constructs that satisfy your requirements.  An example would be:

```
case when xStatus = 'SUCCESS' and yStatus = 'SUCCESS' and zStatus = 'SUCCESS'
then 'Delivered'
when something else then an appropriate value
else default value end "Stucture Status"
```